# Using system proxy in browser and renderer process

Tags: electron, chromium

In my electron app, I have coded a RestClient which is executed in main and renderer process. The first request, done in the main process, is done with the net library from electron and it successfully uses the system proxy settings.

The next request, executed in renderer process cannot use net library, because this belongs to main only. Therefore I switch to normal https request, but this does not use system proxy settings.

Is there a way to use the system proxy in the renderer process?

Edit: Maybe a more general question: What is the best practise in electron to make web requests? Is there some standard way to use http/https, request, net or fetch? Which way would use the system proxy?

Comment: The render processes use IPC to communicate with the main process. So it's the main processes which will communicate with the network and then transfer data to the render process. So I see no reason to use proxy in the render processes.

Comment: @Asesh Okay. But how can I create a REST request in the renderer, which uses the system proxy settings of the OS? (e.g. windows 10) Only "net" library (which is only available in the main process) uses it.

Comment: I would also really like to know the best practice approach to this question.  I have a main process that works via proxy fine, but a renderer that refuses to use the proxy.  Im not entirely sure why

Comment: @KevinZ01 I'm currently trying to do the same as you, but when I use the net library from electron into the main process, it does not uses the system proxy. Did you just used the Net library to perform the request which automatically used the OS system proxy settings ?

Comment: Could you share your eventviewer exception messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i tested this on windows and it runs smoothly with fetch() in the renderer
[image: request with and without system proxy]

---

but i think best practice at this point is to send a message from renderer process via ipcRenderer to the main process.

so in your renderer process send a message with

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipc.send('hello','a string', 10);
```

and in your main process receive the message and make your api request like the first

```
ipc.on('fromMain', (event, messages) => {
    // do your api request and send data back
}
```

after this send the data back to the renderer process

why?
Advantages: strict separation of frontend and backend, only one method for API query and of course "don't repeat yourself"

Comment: This is how we handled it too :)